# pandas dataframe with pathlib Path filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pathlib

I am trying to filter a dataframe like the following by its path and the paths items:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

lst = [('100', Path('/root/sub1/nameA.txt'), 'some_type'),
       ('101', Path('/root/sub1/nameB.txt'), 'some_type'),
       ('102', Path('/root/sub2/nameC.txt'), 'other_type')]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['id', 'path', 'category'])
print(df)
```

At the moment I am looking for all elements, whose parent is sub1 (i.e all files in dir sub1).
Generally I want to be able to filter the df by certain properties of its path.

I know of the `Path.parent` property and have been using it for a while. I am also aware of filter options like `df['path'].str.contains()` which does not work with a path object in the df entry.

Any advice? Thanks for your help!

*answering Manakins questions in the comment - Example Output*

```py
df[df['path'].apply(Path.parent == '/root/sub1')] # does of course not work!

# desired output
df
      id     path                    category
0     100    '/root/sub1/nameA.txt'  'some_type'
1     101    '/root/sub1/nameB.txt'  'some_type'
```

Comment: you'll have to use `.apply` what are you trying to acheive can you post a sample output?

Comment: For a start, I'd like the respective id, so in my example the desired output would be `['100', '101']` or an equivalent representation of the df, respectively. Hope that this answers your question?!

Comment: it doesn't I'm still unclear  (might just be me..!) can you post your output into your post? see [mcve]

Comment: Hope that helps. Of course I cannot really reproduce my desired output, because then I would already have solved the problem :) What I am looking for, is the expression in the line, where I wrote `# does of course not work`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use pathlib objects then you'll have to use apply

```
df[df['path'].apply(lambda x : x.parent == Path('/root/sub1'))]


    id                  path   category
0  100  \root\sub1\nameA.txt  some_type
1  101  \root\sub1\nameB.txt  some_type
```

you could convert the object to a string, but you'd get an absolute path which may not be correct.

Comment: I'll stick to the Path objects and will go with your first suggestion. So Thanks. However by reading `apply()`'s doc I should have been able to figure that out myself...

Comment: small suggestion, that in my case is even more convenient: `df[df['path'].apply(lambda x : x.parent.name == 'sub1')]`. Here one even avoids the Path obj in the `apply` call. Of course that depends on the directory structure.

Comment: yep, but you're still using `apply`, the whole point of using `strings` is to avoid `apply` which iterates and is slower. you could do`df[df['path'].astype(str).str.contains('sub1')]` which will be faster. @Robert

Answer (score 2):

On another platform I was pointed to the **[pandas-path](https://github.com/drivendataorg/pandas-path)** project, which I want to link here as another approach for anybody who might have the same problem, I had. The project provides a [pandas accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html) with pathlib functionality.

*Please note:* I haven't tried or used the linked library in any kind and can therefore not comment on its functionality or usability. I just provide the link as a "helping hand" to anybody who might want to give it a try.

Comment: Package author here. It's a pretty simple wrapper that just maps all the objects to a `Path` object when the accessor is called then back to a string so all the normal pandas things work. We use it regularly for these kind of use cases. `df.filepath.path.parent == '/root/sub1'` as above works as expected in my testing! No need to do any type conversion ahead of time, just `import pandas_path` and the accessor works.